# Lifting ban from Stack Overflow site

Tags: support, ban

Correct me if I am wrong. Is lifting a ban from any one sub site of Stack Exchange by answering questions on any other site or only on that particular site?

I am bannded from Stack Overflow to only asking questions and that too improper. The way it is mentioned here is that the system automatically calculates points internally. So when I start giving answers (I have not given yet), I'll eventually be able to lift this ban. Is it true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only your reputation and history from the site you're blocked on is taken into account for either applying or lifting the ban.  If you're blocked on Stack Overflow, only actions on that site will count towards lifting that block.